# Transfer data from Macbook Pro hard drive into Windows

Tags: hard-drive, backup, macbook-pro, enclosures

I have Macbook Pro hard driven (taken out of 2011 MBP). I have the enclosure and is interface with Windows Laptop. I am recovering data and the hard drive is ok. But I can only access Windows partition on that drive. Is there anyway I can access Mac OS-X files and copy them to Windows. I have Windows 7 and XP (dual boot) on my laptop.

As far as I know, I think I can't, unless there is a software for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install drivers/software that can understand Mac file systems (defaulting to HFS). There are a couple for Windows:

- [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) - Commercial
- [HFS Explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) - Free (though old-ish)
- [jHFSMount](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhfsplus/) - Free, mounts HFS volumes read-only